# difference between an array name and a pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

is the array name is actually like typing the address of the first element of the array ?

based on my understanding of the array name

the array name variable isn't a pointer that has it's own memory address and it's content is the address of the first element of the array

but it's a way of typing the address of first element in a plain english name

i will try now to explain it now visually

consider the following code it will be related to the image i'm about to show you

```
char[] text = "Hey";
char *ptr = text;
```

and now look at the image

[image]

the `*ptr` variable has it's own memory address and the content of the pointer is the memory address of `H` which is `0101`

now the text variable doesn't have it's own memory address when we type text C interprets it to the memory address `0101`

so basically text is 0101

am i right ?

Comment: You might like section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: `text` is the 4 byte area starting at "address 0101"... in many contexts, it is converted (some people say it *decays*) to a pointer to the address 0101.

Comment: there are 2 different things: value (variable) and address. pointer will contain the address of the value (variable)[but it also has it's own address], while text(first array element) contain value but can be referenced as a pointer (==address). when you refer to text as an address it's like to do 'int x;' '&x'. x is the variable and will refer to the value and &x will refer to its address. '&x' == 'text', 'x' == '*text'

Comment: Arrays **HAVE** an address.  That address is always the address of the first element of the array.  Pointers **HOLD** an address.  That address can point anywhere and it may nor may not be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Well, almost but not quite.

`text` is a variable of type `char [4]`, it's an array of `char`s. Now, as per the spec, chapter 6.3.2.1/P3

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

That means,

```
char * ptr = text;
```

is the same as writing

```
char * ptr = &text[0];
```

That said,

> *now the text variable doesn't have it's own memory address when we type text C interprets it to the memory address 0101*

No, this is wrong. The variable `text` has an address (try doing `&text`, it'll be of type `char (*) [4]`). Now, since an array is a collection of same objects (member object type) in contiguous memory locations, the address of the array is the address of the first element of the array, so while printing the address of the array and the address of the first element of the array will turn out to be same - but remember, they certainly do differ in type.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this declaration

```
char[] text = "Hey";
```

is not a valid C construction.:) It seems you mean

```
char text[] = "Hey";
```

An array type and a pointer type are two different types. Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char text[] = "Hello World!";
    char *ptr   = "Hello World!";
    
    printf( "sizeof( text ) = %zu\n", sizeof( text ) );
    printf( "sizeof( ptr ) = %zu\n", sizeof( ptr ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( text ) = 13
sizeof( ptr ) = 8
```

Or if you will apply the address of operator & to the variable text like `&text` then the type of the expression will be `char ( * )[13]`. While applying the operator to the variable `ptr` like `&ptr` then the type of the expression will be `char **`.

Indeed according to the C Standard an array designator is implicitly converted in expressions (except the expressions mentioned above)  to a pointer to its firs element.

So you may write

```
char text[] = "Hey";
char *ptr = text;
```

The values of the expressions `&text` and `ptr` (though they have different types) will be equal because they both point to the initial address of the extent of the memory occupied by the array.

The fact that an array designator is converted to a pointer to its first element is related to how the compiler adjusts a function parameter having an array type to the type of pointer to the array element type. That is for example these two function declarations declare the same one function

```
void f( char s[] );
```

and

```
void f( char *s );
```